# Deleting characters from a string in java

Tags: java, string, replace

```
package nameinput;    
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameInput {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {           
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your value");
        String entered_value;
        entered_value = user_input.next();

        String replace = entered_value.replace("a-z, A-Z", "");
        System.out.println(entered_value);            
    }        
}
```

The above is the code I have written so far. At present, whenever I ran the program, all that happens is the user is asked for their input, and then whatever value is typed, will be repeated back. Therefore, the string replace is not working, I was hoping to strip any entered string of any A-Z, a-z characters and replace them with whitespace.

Sadly, this is not working

Comment: You're not printing the value of `replace`

Comment: While previous comment is true, That is not how you use the `replace` method, unless you literally want to replace the string `"a-z, A-Z"` (comma included and everything)

Comment: Ok, how then WOULD I print the value of replace...?

Comment: Have you tried `replaceAll`, and using a regular expression for the first argument?

Comment: What's your intention? Just to upper case the string? If that's the case you only have to use the toUpperCase method.

Comment: "*Ok, how then WOULD I print the value of replace*" by printing `replace` instead of `entered_value` which still holds original string. Remember that string objects are **immutable** so you can't edit them (but you can reassign string variable to hold other string object). So when you call `original.replace("foo","bar")` it will not modify string held by `original` but will create and *return* new string object which will contain text with replaced characters. In your case you are storing that returned string in `replace`.

Comment: Also "*I was hoping to strip any entered string of any A-Z, a-z characters and replace them with **whitespace***" this `""` is not whitespace. This is *empty string*.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String replace = entered_value.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]+","");
System.out.println(replace);
```

Breakdown of regex:

- [ ... ]  = Character class match: match any of the characters between the brackets
- A-Z     = Shorthand for ABC...XYZ
- a-z     = Shorthandl for abc...zyz
- *x*+    = Match one or more consecutive *x* (the *x* in this case being the whole bracketed character class)

Comment: Why `*`? `+` makes more sense here.

Comment: You might want to explain what the syntax of the regex means for OP

Comment: It should be String replace = entered_value.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]+"," "); That's it, with a whitespace as replacement.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify some things.

1) My original code failed for 2 reasons. One, I used replace which only replaced on a "like for like" basis, i.e. one incidence of one character, with another. The second error was that I was merely repeating the original string value.

2) Therefore, the stringAll function and the regex items are used to remove/edit ALL incidences of the "inappropriate" chars, where they match exactly. (the []+). 

String replace represents a new variable, called replace, which contains the original string, but manipulated with regex. Its then displayed. Amiright

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that seem a bit strange.

Firstly [as stated by @wakjah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416474/deleting-characters-from-a-string-in-java#comment64239960_38416474), you are not printing the string with the characters replaced. You are printing the String with the entered value.

Secondly I do not think that is how the replace methods works. the replace method takes two parameters: the old value which you want to replace and the what you want it to be replaced with.
Thus what `entered_value.replace("a-z, A-Z", "");` means is, if the String contains `"a-z, A-Z"` (it has to match this whole string), then replace it by `""`.

For example the string `"Hello, World!"` will stay the same, because there is no match for the whole string `"a-z, A-Z"`.
But `"Hello a-z, A-Z is going to be replaced"` will become `"Hello  is going to be replaced"`.

A way this could be done is with the `replaceAll` method. This takes a Regex, which could be used to match the whole alphabet.

Comment: I thought that the  System.out.println(entered_value); line was merely stating the data AFTER it had been edited sorry

Comment: No problem, we are here to help:)